# Converting 24-hour clock time to am/pm in Joda-Time

Tags: java, jodatime

I just started working with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), and got it to correctly display my date in [24-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) ("military time") but I would rather it be am/pm.  Looked it up and it mentioned [hourOfDay](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#hourOfDay%28%29) which I figured was the HH value so I tried to write a loop that would break it down into AM/Pm but it never worked out.

```
    DateTime dtf = new DateTime(wikiParsedDate);


    if (hourOfDay == 00) {
        hourOfDay == 12;
        DateTimeFormatter builder = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS'AM" );
        return builder.print(dtf);
    } else if (0 < hourOfDay && hourOfDay < 12) {
        DateTimeFormatter builder = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS'AM" );
        return builder.print(dtf);
    } else if (hourOfDay > 12) {
        hourOfDay - 12 == hourOfDay;
        DateTimeFormatter builder = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS'PM" );
        return builder.print(dtf);
    }

}
```

Comment: `hourOfDay - 12 == hourOfDay;` seems to wrong. Do you mean `hourOfDay -= 12;`? But that also wont work. It must be something like `dtf = dtf.withHourOfDay(dtf.getHourOfDay()-12)` but that is also incorrect, as it should be left to the formatter to write AM or PM

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Look at the API documentation of [`DateTimeFormat`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html). This should do what you want:

```
DateTimeFormatter builder = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSa");
```

No need for the complication with different cases.

Comment: And look at `DateTimeFormat.forStyle` to generate string representations with format and language localized for a particular [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

Comment: What's .SSa?  Is that a whitespace followed by am/pm?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky No. See the API docs of [`DateTimeFormat`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html). `SS` = fractions of a second, `a` = AM/PM.