# Converting minutes to time of day in my Java program

Tags: java

I am writing a program to convert minutes into the time of day. How can I write this to keep the hours in standard time, the hour should never exceed 12.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MinutesConverter {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      int minutes;
      int hours;

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter minutes: ");
      minutes = input.nextInt();


      hours = minutes / 60;
      minutes %= 60;

      System.out.print(hours + ":" + minutes);

   }
}
```

Comment: Currently lets say I input 800 minutes, my code will print 13:20 but that is military time. I want it to display in standard time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert a 4-digit military time into the standard 12 hour time format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342596/convert-a-4-digit-military-time-into-the-standard-12-hour-time-format)

Comment: I saw that one but that didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a little change in code, where you are assigning value to `hour`

here is what i can suggest:

```
hour = ( minutes / 60 ) % 24;
```

Comment: Actually, so after I use that code, it does convert it but it is converting to the wrong time. Example, I input 915 minutes it should come out to 3:15 but it is coming out to 12:15

Comment: It needs to be the other way round: `hour = (minutes / 60) %12` then it'll work

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.

Comment: Any idea why when I enter 120 minutes it will output 2:0 instead of 2:00

Comment: Because `minutes` variable is an integer, and For any Integer `00` is actually `0`.