# Android joda time convert from 24 to 12

Tags: android, mysql, jodatime

I am inserting the date to database like this:

```
long d = cal.getTimeInMillis();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String time_string_f=dateFormat.format(d);
```

time_string_f is the string to insert in database , and the output is like:

```
07/09/2015 20:47:00
```

I want to get it from database and format it to be 12 hours with am/pm.

So I got this solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075188/converting-24-hour-clock-time-to-am-pm-in-joda-time)

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSa");
DateTime jodatime = dtf.parseDateTime(string_date_from_database);
int yy= jodatime.getYear();
```

I am getting the year just to check if it works.

but it does not work and gives me this error:

```
07-09 22:34:48.399: I/FFFFF(7165): Invalid format: "07/09/2015 20:47:00" is malformed     at "/09/2015 20:47:00"
```

Comment: Why are you inserting it into the database as a string in the first place? The problem with the parse operation is that the value simply doesn't match the format you've specified... if you've really got text in the database, you need to parse with one format, then format with the desired output format. But you'd be better off storing it as a datetime.

Comment: i am fetching it from database and format it and use it very will , although it is a text ... the problem is only when i try to convert it from 24 to 12  , i am use Calendar and joda time in the same app this why i am keeping it text , this works for me :   DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            DateTime jodatime = dtf.parseDateTime(date); , but it still 24 houres

Comment: The `DateTime` doesn't have a format - if you need a particular *text* representation, you need to format it at that point. But again, you really *really* shouldn't just store it as text (especially in a format like that). All kinds of things are better if you use the appropriate field type. Do you use text for *all* your database fields?

Comment: you are right ... i should not use text field for date ... it was a mistake ... thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value in you database has format `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` - without AM/PM suffix.
So you should parse is without `a` option and then convert date to 12 hours format.
Example:

```
   String string_date_from_database = "07/09/2015 20:47:00"; 
   DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
   DateTime jodatime = dtf.parseDateTime(string_date_from_database);
   String dateIn12HourFormat = jodatime.toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ssa");   
   // Now 'dateIn12HourFormat' looks like `07/09/2015 08:47:00PM`
```

You can use simple utility method:

```
   static final DateTimeFormatter hours24 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
   static final DateTimeFormatter hours12 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ssa");
   static String convertTo12HoursFormat(String format24hours)
   {
      return hours12.print(hours24.parseDateTime(format24hours));
   }
```

Usage:

```
   String string_date_from_database = "07/09/2015 20:47:00";
   String dateIn12HourFormat = convertTo12HoursFormat(string_date_from_database);
```

Comment: `jodatime.toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ssa");` that solved my problem .. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try like the following.

```
long d = cal.getTimeInMillis();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
String time_string_f=dateFormat.format(d);
```

Comment: gives me this error : Invalid format: "07/09/2015 20:47:00" is too short